# pandas create a new column of item pairs

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe like this:

| orderID | Product | PurchaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 08/05/2021 |
| 123 | B | 08/05/2021 |
| 123 | C | 08/05/2021 |
| 123 | D | 08/05/2021 |
| 245 | B | 11/05/2021 |
| 245 | C | 11/05/2021 |
| 245 | A | 11/05/2021 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to create a column of product pairs so my new df would be:

| orderID | ProductPairs | PurchaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A,B | 08/05/2021 |
| 123 | B,C | 08/05/2021 |
| 123 | C,D | 08/05/2021 |
| 123 | A,C | 08/05/2021 |
| 123 | B,D | 08/05/2021 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Any idea how to do this with pandas?

Comment: Can you explain how to group the products? What is logic of grouping A,B ? Group the products with same orderID? If you want to group products with same orderID what do you want to do with the date?

Comment: Yeah, I want to group product-pairs bought (in separate purchases) according to orderID and calculate the average intervals between them.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more explanation- why does D get 08/05/2021?

Comment: Also a little unclear also why 245 doesn't appear in output. Do you want separate frames per orderID? something else?

Comment: This table is an example there are more than 2 order ids and more than 4 products, but no I don't want saperated dataframes, All in one. I hope that everything is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try with [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) + [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) + [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode):

```
from itertools import combinations

new_df = (
    df.groupby(['orderID', 'PurchaseDate'])['Product']
        .agg(lambda p: list(combinations(p, 2)))
        .explode()
        .str.join(',')
        .reset_index(name='ProductPairs')
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   orderID PurchaseDate ProductPairs
0      123   08/05/2021          A,B
1      123   08/05/2021          A,C
2      123   08/05/2021          A,D
3      123   08/05/2021          B,C
4      123   08/05/2021          B,D
5      123   08/05/2021          C,D
6      245   11/05/2021          B,C
7      245   11/05/2021          B,A
8      245   11/05/2021          C,A
```